# How can I trace inconsistency in loading a template?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I have two (almost) identical wordpress websites. A devel/local and a production/remote. I have a custom post type "event" created through Meta Mask on both instances. I want to render a template "archive-event.php" by adding a "/event" request in the browser. The devel instance renders the archive-event.php well. The production instance renders a 404.php template, although the archive-event.php template is in the right place.

Query Monitor shows this:

### Devel

#### Overview

```
GET http://[local site]/event/ → 200
```

#### Request

```
event
Matched Rule

event/?$
Matched Query

post_type=event
Query String

post_type=event

All Matching Rewrite Rules
event/?$    post_type=event
(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$    pagename=$matches[1]
&page=$matches[2]
(.+?)/?$    category_name=$matches[1]
```

### Prod

#### Overview

```
GET https://[remote site]/event/ → 404
```

#### Request

```
event
Matched Rule

(.+?)/?$
Matched Query

category_name=event
Query String

category_name=event

All Matching Rewrite Rules
(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$    pagename=$matches[1]
&page=$matches[2]
(.+?)/?$    category_name=$matches[1]
```

How can I trace where is the conflict or another difference?

Comment: If you registered the post type with a plugin then it's probably configured differently on each. Archives need to be enabled for the post type. In code that's making sure that `has_archive` is `true`, but if you used a plugin you'd need to ask its author how to do this. Third party plugins are off topic here.

Comment: Actually there's no difference between creating a custom post type through Meta Box and through plain WordPress. It's just a code generator, so we can consider it a pluginless way. I will check the `has_archive`, thanks for your tip.

Comment: No, it isn't a `has_archive` issue. It seems to be a slug conflict. `?post_type=event` works well.

Comment: Did you re-save permalink settings on the prod site?

Comment: Bingo! I re-saved the permalink settings and it is working well now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by missing permalinks for the new content types. Re-saving the permalink settings helped.